# View Last 3 Most Recent Images Taken With Camera In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to display last 3 images in the **camera roll**/**gallery**/**photos** from my app. How do I achieve this in Flutter?

Any ideas?

Suppose I want to see the latest images in the DCIM folder. How do we do this?

Comment: Please check this: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/676/commits/5c1e946f29aea8c80e631b55035c87bfe2f9f0f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope what you're looking for will be solved by using this package [photo_gallery](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_gallery)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, however it doesn't let us specify how to "identify" which picture is from the Camera folder

Answer (score 0):

Never used this package before, but it seems to fit your needs.

Try to use [media_picker_widget](https://media_picker_widget:%20%5E0.0.9) as its supports presenting specific amount of images from different albums using custom widgets.

Check out the official example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:media_picker_widget/media_picker_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Media Picker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Media> mediaList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Image Picker'),
      ),
      body: previewList(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => openImagePicker(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget previewList() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 96,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: List.generate(
            mediaList.length,
            (index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 80,
                    child: Image.memory(
                      mediaList[index].thumbnail,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openImagePicker(BuildContext context) {
    // openCamera(onCapture: (image){
    //   setState(()=> mediaList = [image]);
    // });
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return MediaPicker(
            mediaList: mediaList,
            onPick: (selectedList) {
              setState(() => mediaList = selectedList);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            onCancel: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            mediaCount: MediaCount.multiple,
            mediaType: MediaType.image,
            decoration: PickerDecoration(
              actionBarPosition: ActionBarPosition.top,
              blurStrength: 2,
              completeText: 'Next',
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: @JayVDiyk have you tried this package?